# Core Data how to retrieve a column from an entity

Tags: ios, core-data, primary-key

I am using Core Data for my ios app and I am wondering how would I go about in retrieving an entire column from an entity table? For example I am soly interested in grabbing the primary key from my table.

In sql i would just do Select name from MYTABLE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could do it this way :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"--table--" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

NSMutableArray *elementsFromColumn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSManagedObject *fetchedObject in fetchedObjects) {
    [elementsFromColumn addObject:[fetchedObject valueForKey:@"--column--"]];
}
```

So you have all the elements from a specific column of your table.
Hope it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: That worked. Thanks for posting. now if only i can figure out how to get this darn auto-complete feature done I'd be happy.

Comment: @bs7 so CoreData fetches all the available columns when I executeFetchRequest or it only fetches when I call valueForKey ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setPropertiesToFetch%3a) for NSFetchRequest. You can ask it to return dictionaries containing specific properties only - this is about as close as you will get. The methods of interest are `setResultType:` and `setPropertiesToFetch:`.